# How do I prohibit the generation of a large number of files when I use package "compression-webpack-plugin" in node module

Tags: javascript, node-modules

When I edit code and compile  there are generate files in

```
\node_modules\.cache\compression-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512
```

How should I do  to dont  generate cache files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you webpack version is 4.x, you can set cache value to `false`,example:

```
 new CompressionWebpackPlugin({ cache: false })
```

if you webpack version is 5.x, you can set cache too , but something is defferent, you can see this :[webpack 5.x document cache](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#root)